# How to write triangle with stars in Php. (*) I want to do it with while

Tags: php, triangle

I did this with a "for" loop. How can I write this with while. Thank you for your help. I just started learning PHP.

```
for ($a=0; $a <=10 ; $a++) { 
    for ($y=0; $y <= $a ; $y++) { 
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
for ($a=10; $a >=1 ; $a--) { 
    for ($y=1; $y <= $a ; $y++) { 
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but your inner loop can be replaced with `echo str_repeat('*', $a);`

Answer (score 1):

The trick to rewriting a `for` statement to a `while` statement is extracting the incrementer initialization (`$a = 0`) and the incrementation (`$a++`) itself.

So

```
for ($a=0; $a <=10 ; $a++)
```

becomes

```
$a = 0;
while ($a <=10) {
    $a++;
}
```

#### Result

```
$a = 0;

while ($a <=10) {
    $y = 0;
    while ($y <= $a) { 
        echo "*";
        $y++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $a++;
}

$a = 10;

while ($a >=1) { 
    $y = 1;
    while ($y <= $a) { 
        echo "*";
        $y++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $a--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=10; $i<80; $i+=4) {
  // do something
}
```

is equivalent  to:

```
$i=10
while ($i<80) {
  // do something
   $i+=4;
}
```